# miniconda Solving environment: failed ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I work in Ubuntu 18 and I try to create env with miniconda3.6 from file with this line

```
conda env create -f module.yml
```

but i have this error

```
  Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - libpng==1.6.32=h6184301_3
  - pyopenssl==17.2.0=py36h5d7bf08_0
  - xlrd==1.1.0=py36h336f4a2_1
  - ncurses==6.0=hd04f020_2
  - terminado==0.6=py36h656782e_0
  - icu==58.2=h4b95b61_1
  - urllib3==1.22=py36h68b9469_0
  - pyqt==5.6.0=py36he5c6137_6
  - python==3.6.3=h5ce8c04_4
  - nbconvert==5.3.1=py36h810822e_0
  - jpeg==9b=he5867d9_2
  - wheel==0.29.0=py36h3597b6d_1
```

my coda info look like this

```
     active environment : None
       user config file : /home/john/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.5.8
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.6.5.final.0
       base environment : /home/john/miniconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
          package cache : /home/john/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /home/john/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/john/miniconda3/envs
                          /home/john/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.8 requests/2.19.1 CPython/3.6.5 Linux/4.15.0-29-generic ubuntu/18.04 glibc/2.27
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

my module.yml i have trim it because is very big

```
name: py4fi
channels:
- defaults
dependencies:
- appnope=0.1.0=py36hf537a9a_0
- asn1crypto=0.22.0=py36hb705621_1
- bleach=2.0.0=py36h8fcea71_0
- bzip2=1.0.6=h649919c_2
- ca-certificates=2017.08.26=ha1e5d58_0
- certifi=2017.7.27.1=py36hd973bb6_0
- cffi=1.10.0=py36h880867e_1
- chardet=3.0.4=py36h96c241c_1
- click=6.7=py36hec950be_0
```

i try update et delete and reinstall miniconda but i have always this probleme my terminale is a zsh i dont know if it can help you

Comment: Apparently those packages aren't available for Linux. What OS was the yaml file created on?

Comment: The Os that the yaml file created is Mac OS

Comment: Right, so these package versions with the hash are probably specifically for macOS then. You'll need to delete everything after the second equals sign